# Zend 2: How to set session in AJAX request

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2

Normaly I dont have any problem with setting session in controller's action. I do following:

```
    public function testAction()
    {
        $container = new Container('example');
        $container->test = 'example';
        ...
    }
```

And it works. However if it's AJAX call it doesn't work...

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
        ...
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // code that works fine

            // session code that doesn't work at all...
            $container = new Container('example');
            var_dump($container->test); // <-- in second request it should dump 'example' string, but it returns null every time
            $container->test = 'example';
        }

        return new JsonModel(array('success' => $result));
}
```

I tried above code with following methods:

```
$container->getManager()->start()
$container->getManager()->isValid()
$container->getManager()->getStorage()->isLocked()
$container->getManager()->rememberMe(30*60*60*24);
$container->setExpirationSeconds(30*60*60*24);
$container->getManager()->getConfig()->setCookieSecure(false);
$container->getManager()->getConfig()->setCookieHttpOnly(false);
$container->getManager()->writeClose();
```

But it doesn't work. AJAX requests are run by standard jQuery method so I don't think it's worth posting it. I'm pretty sure AJAX call working just fine, because I don't have any problrm except this one.

Any idea what should I do to be able to set session variables in AJAX?
What does Zend change/block that it does work with normal HTTP request, but not with AJAX.

Comment: The first argument of Container::construct() is the session namespace. Before assigning `$container->test = 'example';`it's normal that your var_dump return null.

Comment: @AlainPomirol Yes, I know. As I said in commented text it should return `example` in next request (first it should return null, then it should return `example` as long as session exisits)